# Can't paste image in square with a loop

Tags: python, image, for-loop, python-imaging-library, paste

I can't achieve to paste images in a square form (if I choose 9 for `n_album`, I should have a 3x3 collage). It only works for 1x1, if it's more it will paste the same image where another image is supposed to be.

Here is my code:

```
def make_montage(n_album, path):
    x_offset = width    #Constant resized image width
    y_offset = height   #Constant resized image height
    c = []
    x = 0
    img = Image.new('RGB', (n_album*height + y_offset*2, n_album*width + x_offset*2), color = (0, 0, 0))

    for file_name in os.listdir(path):
        print(f"Processing {file_name}")
        c.append(file_name)

    print(f"root of n_album = {int(math.sqrt(n_album))}")
    #Loop in square
    for i in range(int(math.sqrt(n_album))):
        for j in range(int(math.sqrt(n_album))):
            try:
                cover = Image.open(os.path.join(path, c[i + j]))
                print(f"Pasting {str(c[i + j])}")
                img.paste(cover, (int(i * height + y_offset), int(j * width + x_offset)))
            except:
                print("Je code mal mdr")

    img.save(f'{path}\\{n_album}x{n_album}_musical.png')

    #Clean
    for file_name in os.listdir(path):
        if file_name != f'{n_album}x{n_album}_musical.png':
            print(f"Deleting {file_name}")
            os.remove(os.path.join(path, file_name))
```

And here's a result for a 2x2 with images of (the order it was supposed to be pasted): Link, Mario, Princess Zelda, Peach.

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

I see several issues in your code:

- In your method declaration, you should also pass the (desired) width and height of each image. (As is, your method assumes, that `width` and `height` are properly set outside.) This has also the advantage, that you can resize your images on-the-fly within your loop.
- You don't pay attention, when to use `n_album` and when `int(math.sqrt(n_album))`. (See your 2x2 montage: You obviously initialized a 4x4 montage.) For the latter, create a variable like `n_per_axis`, so you don't have this `math.sqrt` term all the time.
- In your nested loop, you have `i = 1, 2, 3`, and `j = 1, 2, 3`. Using `c[i + j]` then isn't the correct way to access the proper images from `c`. (In your 2x2 montage, you get (0 + 1) = 1 and (1 + 0) = 1, so Mario two times.) Set up a (global) image counter (let's say `k`), and increment it with each entering of the inner loop.
- Don't post code including deleting of files, if that's not the main point of your question.

Here's your code with some modifications:

```py
def make_montage(n_album, path, width, height):         # <-- Width, height!?
    x_offset = width
    y_offset = height
    c = []
    n_per_axis = int(math.sqrt(n_album))
    img = Image.new('RGB',
                    (n_per_axis*height + y_offset*2,    # <-- n per axis!?
                     n_per_axis*width + x_offset*2),    # <-- n per axis!?
                    color=(0, 0, 0))

    for file_name in os.listdir(path):
        print(f"Processing {file_name}")
        c.append(file_name)

    print(f"root of n_album = {n_per_axis}")
    # Loop in square
    k = -1                                          # <-- Image counter
    for i in range(n_per_axis):
        for j in range(n_per_axis):
            k += 1
            try:
                cover = Image.open(os.path.join(path, c[k]))\
                    .resize((width, height))        # <-- Might be omitted here
                print(f"Pasting {str(c[k])}")
                img.paste(cover,
                          (int(i * height + y_offset),
                           int(j * width + x_offset)))
            except:
                print("Je code mal mdr")

    img.save(f'{path}\\{n_per_axis}x{n_per_axis}_musical.png')  # <-- n per axis!?

    for file_name in os.listdir(path):
        if file_name != f'{n_per_axis}x{n_per_axis}_musical.png':
            print(f"Deleting {file_name}")
            #os.remove(os.path.join(path, file_name))
```

Using

```py
make_montage(9, 'path_with_nine_images/', 100, 100)
```

I get the following output:

[image: Output]

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you ! About the resizing, i've made another function to resize all the image from my image folder